# Shortcut for selecting all below lines from current dragged line in IntelliJ or GoLand on Mac?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, goland

In VS Code, I can select the current line with <kbd>Cmd + Shift + Right Arrow</kbd>. Then I can do <kbd>Cmd + Shift + Down Arrow</kbd> to select all below lines from the currently selected lines. But I think <kbd>Cmd + Shift + Down Arrow</kbd> is not working as I expected in JetBrains world.

Does anyone know what is the IntelliJ or GoLand's shortcut which is equivalent to <kbd>Cmd + Shift + Down Arrow</kbd> in VS Code?

Comment: **1)** `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Keymap` **2)** Type `select` in the local search field and check the list of available actions. You may be after "Down with Selection" action (that selects the next line only) .. or based on "**selecting ALL below lines"* it could be "Move Caret to Text End with Selection" (which is `Ctrl+Shift+End` here on Windows keymap)

Comment: Press fn key with Cmd + Shift + Down Arrow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an `End` Button is not present on the Mac keyboard. On the other hand, there is a keymap on JetBrains IDEs ( like Golang ) on Macos that moves the line down ( Preferences -> Keymap -> Main Menu -> Code -> Move Line Down ) that is set to `Options + Shift + Down Arrow`, but it surprisingly also hits when you try to use `Cmd` instead of `Options`.

My current solution is that if you don't have an alternative keyboard, use `Fn + Down Arrow` for the `End` button, so you can use `Fn + Shift + Down Arrow` to select all of the below lines of your current line.